# Chat usando php e msql

Tags: php, mysql, chat

Queria saber como posso com php pegar o id de outro usuário online, sem ser pelo nome, pq pode haver usuários com o nome idêntico. por exemplo puxar a id de outro usuário, não sei como fazer isso (full iniciante)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal é você pegar pelo usuário. E o mesmo deve ser único para não ocorrer duplicidade. Coloque o campo como UNIQUE no seu banco de dados e na aplicação antes de inserir um novo usuário verifique se o mesmo não existe.

Comment: como eu poderia pegar o nome dessa pessoa com o php, pra poder inserir no bd?

Comment: Não tinha entendido bem sua pergunta. Todos os dados necessários para o chat devem ser inseridos pelo usuário através de formulário. Para você pegar os usuários ativos é necessário você criar um campo em sua tabela de usuários que pode chamar de ativo. Quando o usuário autenticar em seu site você atualizar o campo ativo para 1. E quando fazer log out o campo ativo seria 0. Ou seja os usuários online são os que estão com campo ativo 1.

Comment: neste caso eu quero por exemplo clicar no usuário tal e pegar o nome dele pra buscar a id no bd e gerar uma sala. ai sempre que o usuário for falar com akela pessoa eu posso trazer as mensagens deles. ja achei umas versões publicas mais em todas os usuários entram com o nick e falam em uma unica sala, no caso eu queria uma sala pra cada conversa entre dois usuários, mais naum achei nem um conteúdo explicando como fazer isso.

Comment: O ideal no seu link de cada usuário na lista de usuários online é conter o id do usuário para pegar o restante dos dados e pegar os dados necessários. O ideal é você mostrar o que tem feito e o que necessita.

Comment: vou tentar fazer com o q vc me falou e depois mando o codigo